# why my lightning component not showing colors for h1?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

My component  has simple line

```
  <aura:component >
   <h1>This is token Test</h1>    
</aura:component>
```

Below are my css code. but its not showing the expected output.

```
 .THIS h1 {
   background-color: #0040ff;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at e.g. [How CSS Selectors Work](https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/) to get some insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may include class for particular `<h1>` tag

**In component**

```
<aura:component >
    <h1 class="as">This is token Test</h1>    
</aura:component>
```

**css:**

```
 .THIS.as {
   background-color: #0040ff;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

**Or if want to use global to `<h1>` tag**

**In component**

```
<aura:component >
    <h1>This is token Test</h1>    
</aura:component>
```

CSS:

```
h1.THIS{
       background-color: #0040ff;
       color: #fff;
       padding: 10px 20px;
}
```